# How to replace numbers when importing from csv file into python

Tags: python, regex, csv, import, edit

I'm currently working on a Python script to pull in data from a csv file to generate cisco ASR config utilizing a Jinja2 template. All of that is working fine; however, I need to modify one row so that the generated output will be in the correct ASR configuration syntax. I have hundreds of these to do and would love to simply be able to generate the ASR config properly for a simple copy and paste into devices. Could someone please guide me on the easiest way to do this?

My Python script:

```
import os
import jinja2
import csv
import re

# csv fileused
csv_file = "BFL1_AR1.csv"
with open(csv_file) as f:
    read_csv = csv.DictReader(f)
    for list_elements in read_csv:
        generated_list = list_elements['TEST']
        generated_list = generated_list.split()
        list_elements['TEST'] = generated_list
        pattern = re.findall('4323:(\d{1,9})\:\DD', )
        print (pattern)

        template_file = 'asr_generate_config.j2'
        with open(template_file) as f:
            list_template = f.read()

        template = jinja2.Template(list_template)
        print()
        print('-' * 80)
        print(template.render(list_elements))
        print('-' * 80)
        print()
```

Generated output:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
l2vpn bridge group 4323:63210:BD
l2vpn bridge group 4323:63210:BD bridge-domain 4323:63210:BD
l2vpn bridge group 4323:63210:BD bridge-domain 4323:63210:BD mac withdraw state-down
l2vpn bridge group 4323:63210:BD bridge-domain 4323:63210:BD mtu 9216
l2vpn bridge group 4323:63210:BD bridge-domain 4323:63210:BD interface be10.149
l2vpn bridge group 4323:63210:BD bridge-domain 4323:63210:BD interface be50.149
l2vpn bridge group 4323:63210:BD bridge-domain 4323:63210:BD vfi 4323:63210:BD
l2vpn bridge group 4323:63210:BD bridge-domain 4323:63210:BD vfi 4323:63210:BD vpn-id 1024571
l2vpn bridge group 4323:63210:BD bridge-domain 4323:63210:BD vfi 4323:63210:BD autodiscovery bgp
l2vpn bridge group 4323:63210:BD bridge-domain 4323:63210:BD vfi 4323:63210:BD autodiscovery bgp rd auto
l2vpn bridge group 4323:63210:BD bridge-domain 4323:63210:BD vfi 4323:63210:BD autodiscovery bgp route-target 4323:63210
interface be10.149 l2transport
interface be10.149 l2transport description CA/KXFN/201755/LVLC
interface be10.149 l2transport encapsulation dot1q 149
interface be10.149 l2transport rewrite ingress tag pop 1 symmetric
interface be10.149 l2transport ethernet-services access-group L2-FRAMES ingress
interface be50.149 l2transport
interface be50.149 l2transport description CA/KXFN/201755/LVLC
interface be50.149 l2transport encapsulation dot1q 149
interface be50.149 l2transport rewrite ingress tag pop 1 symmetric
interface be50.149 l2transport ethernet-services access-group L2-FRAMES ingress
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What I need to change:

Every instance that has this data format:
4323:63210:BD --> 4323_63210

The bridge group ID will stay the same for every customer. I need to change the first semicolon to an underscore and remove the last semicolon and B & D letters. I have been trying to do this with regex & re.findall but haven't had much luck.

CSV file:

```
AR Unit ID  AR_VLAN TEST    CIRCUIT oline lookup    uni lookup  oline dummy service reference   oline svlan assignment  oline_BD_assignment oline_RT_assignment oline_vpnid_assignment  end point node  ring id Add BFL1-AR1/ 6K Topology   New Router Port New_US_6K_Port  Add 6K / 7609 Topology  New_DS_6K_Port  New 6K Port
4   4   MATCH   66/KDFN/102901/TWCS 66/KDFN/102901/TWCS_O_Line  66/KDFN/102901/TWCS DUMMY_OLINE_SVC173  4   4323:63163:BD   4323:63163  1024524 BKFECAAAI6001   #N/A    00GZPP/GE1L/BKFECAAA/BKFECAAA   ae10.4  be10.4  00GZQB/GE1L/BKFECAAA/BKFECAAA   be50.4  Po50.4
15  15  MATCH   66/KEFN/102374/TWCS 66/KEFN/102374/TWCS_O_Line  66/KEFN/102374/TWCS DUMMY_OLINE_SVC176  15  4323:63166:BD   4323:63166  1024527 BKFECAUZW2001   N66200  00GZPP/GE1L/BKFECAAA/BKFECAAA   ae10.15 be10.15 00GZQB/GE1L/BKFECAAA/BKFECAAA   be50.15 Po50.15
39  39  MATCH   66/KEFN/102539/TWCS 66/KEFN/102539/TWCS_O_Line  66/KEFN/102539/TWCS DUMMY_OLINE_SVC177  39  4323:63167:BD   4323:63167  1024528 BKFDCA12NN001   N66204  00GZPP/GE1L/BKFECAAA/BKFECAAA   ae10.39 be10.39 00GZQB/GE1L/BKFECAAA/BKFECAAA   be50.39 Po50.39
50  50  MATCH   66/KFFN/102600/TWCS 66/KFFN/102600/TWCS_O_Line  66/KFFN/102600/TWCS DUMMY_OLINE_SVC203  50  4323:63193:BD   4323:63193  1024554 SHFTCADIW2001   N66198  00GZPP/GE1L/BKFECAAA/BKFECAAA   ae10.50 be10.50 00GZQB/GE1L/BKFECAAA/BKFECAAA   be50.50 Po50.50
```

Jinja2 Template

```
l2vpn bridge group {{ oline_BD_assignment }}
l2vpn bridge group {{ oline_BD_assignment }} bridge-domain {{ oline_BD_assignment }}
l2vpn bridge group {{ oline_BD_assignment }} bridge-domain {{ oline_BD_assignment }} mac withdraw state-down
l2vpn bridge group {{ oline_BD_assignment }} bridge-domain {{ oline_BD_assignment }} mtu 9216
l2vpn bridge group {{ oline_BD_assignment }} bridge-domain {{ oline_BD_assignment }} interface {{ New_US_6K_Port }}
l2vpn bridge group {{ oline_BD_assignment }} bridge-domain {{ oline_BD_assignment }} interface {{ New_DS_6K_Port }}
l2vpn bridge group {{ oline_BD_assignment }} bridge-domain {{ oline_BD_assignment }} vfi {{ oline_BD_assignment }}
l2vpn bridge group {{ oline_BD_assignment }} bridge-domain {{ oline_BD_assignment }} vfi {{ oline_BD_assignment }} vpn-id {{ oline_vpnid_assignment }}
l2vpn bridge group {{ oline_BD_assignment }} bridge-domain {{ oline_BD_assignment }} vfi {{ oline_BD_assignment }} autodiscovery bgp
l2vpn bridge group {{ oline_BD_assignment }} bridge-domain {{ oline_BD_assignment }} vfi {{ oline_BD_assignment }} autodiscovery bgp rd auto
l2vpn bridge group {{ oline_BD_assignment }} bridge-domain {{ oline_BD_assignment }} vfi {{ oline_BD_assignment }} autodiscovery bgp route-target {{ oline_RT_assignment }}
interface {{ New_US_6K_Port }} l2transport
interface {{ New_US_6K_Port }} l2transport description {{CIRCUIT}}
interface {{ New_US_6K_Port }} l2transport encapsulation dot1q {{ AR_VLAN }}
interface {{ New_US_6K_Port }} l2transport rewrite ingress tag pop 1 symmetric
interface {{ New_US_6K_Port }} l2transport ethernet-services access-group L2-FRAMES ingress
interface {{ New_DS_6K_Port }} l2transport
interface {{ New_DS_6K_Port }} l2transport description {{CIRCUIT}}
interface {{ New_DS_6K_Port }} l2transport encapsulation dot1q {{ AR_VLAN }}
interface {{ New_DS_6K_Port }} l2transport rewrite ingress tag pop 1 symmetric
interface {{ New_DS_6K_Port }} l2transport ethernet-services access-group L2-FRAMES ingress
```

Answer (score 0):

If your IDs are always going to be in that general form:

```
pattern = r'(?P<name>[0-9]{4}:[0-9]{5})'
re.findall(pattern, test_value)
# Will return a list of matches, which you can then substitute the : for a _
```

Or if you want to be more specific to make sure you match the `:BD` suffix as well:

```
pattern = r'(?P<name>[0-9]{4}:[0-9]{5}):[A-Z]{2}'
```

Adding some edits after getting a few more details:

```
def convert(old_id):
    pattern = r'(?P<name>[0-9]{4}:[0-9]{5})'
    matches = re.match(pattern, old_id)
    if matches:
        match=matches[0]
    else:
        return 'some_default'
    return match.replace(':','_')
```

or without regex:

```
def convert_simple(old_id):
    return '_'.join(old_id.split(':')[:2])
```

However this does no validation on the form of the ID so if you are confident that the IDs are all correct in the csv then go for it.

You can use that method to convert from the form with the `:` format of the ID to the format with the `_`

Then in your code I would get the old ID with

```
old_id = list_elements['oline_BD_assignment']
new_id = convert(old_id)
list_elements['oline_BD_assignment'] = new_id
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I was trying you first solution and I get the following error:             Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\AC95991\Python3 projects\ASR config generator.py", line 15, in <module>
    re.findall(pattern, test_value)
NameError: name 'test_value' is not defined

Comment: No worries - I just put in a generic variable name `test_value` but you want to replace that with the variable that is storing each line you want to extract the bridge-domain from

Comment: Will. I'm so new to programming. I'm not fully understanding. Does the needed variable get defined within the for loop? And what would the variable be equal to? Please help me understand.

Comment: Thats alright - I am not sure I will be able to really help you without knowing the contents of the csv file and the template to understand how you are manipulating each row of the csv file. 

But basically it sounds like you'll probably want another loop that iterates over each element of `list_elements` and run the match on each line to extract the bridge ID and then replace it with the ID in the format you want. That is if I have correctly guessed what your template is doing from the output you provided.

Comment: That is the column headers and one row of the csv file. There are hundreds of rows with the CSV file. I'm only grabbing specific columns out of there to be put in the Jinja2 template to generate the config.

Comment: Could you please provide me an example of what the code would look like that I would need to include? At this point I have spent way too much time on trying to figure this out and I'm about halfway on giving up! :( Both excited and frustrated. Thought this was going to be easier...

Comment: Will added a portion of the CSV file contents & Jinja2 Template to my original question. So you had a better picture of what I was trying to do. Thank you!

Comment: You are significantly closer than you think you are!

Comment: I have edited my answer with a snippet you can add to your code to do the conversion from the one format to the other and a recommendation of how to grab it.

Comment: Hey Will. Was on vacation. Needed some time away. I will be taking another attempt at this today. Thank you for all your help so far.

Comment: Will that worked! Thank you so much! Could you explain what this line is doing: pattern = r'(?P<name>[0-9]{4}:[0-9]{5})'. I'm not familiar with the ?P<name>

Comment: Glad that has worked for you :+1: Sure - iirc its called a capture block in regex and basically allows for capturing values that match the pattern by name so it can be referenced by its name instead of having to look at all the matches an expression can produce.

Comment: Thank you Will for the explaination. I have one last question. Could you please explain this section to me:                                                                                                               "old_id = list_elements['oline_BD_assignment']
 new_id = convert(old_id)
 list_elements['oline_BD_assignment'] = new_id"

Comment: Yep, so since you are using a DictReader to read the csv all of your columns with be lists that are referenced in the `list_elements` variable. First you grab the list with all of the raw domain names in it and convert all of them to the format you need and then you reinsert them into the `list_elements` variable. The Jinja template you have then iterates over all of the items and builds up the template for you.

Comment: Ok I think I understand everything now. Thank you for all your help Will. I really appreciate you taking the time to help and explain everything! Can't thank you enough!

Comment: No problem at all! I wish you the best with the project and the new year :)

Comment: Thank you again so much for all the help! Merry Christmas and Happy New Years to you and your family!

Comment: Will got one more question for you. I didn't notice earlier but the script is stopping where my spreadsheet has missing data: --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\AC95991\Python3 projects\ASR config generator.py", line 23, in <module>
    new_id = convert(old_id)
  File "c:\Users\AC95991\Python3 projects\ASR config generator.py", line 19, in convert
    match=matches[0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: How do I get it to ignore those rows? Do I need to include some error correcting?

Comment: Hi Javier, not sure if you sorted this or not. You need to check if a match was found in the `convert` function. I will update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: I would advise updating the default string if no match is found or return None and handle that in the main function if you want to skip the row if no ID is found.

Comment: Will yes that worked out. I left my code as you demonstrated. It now generates: i.e. 'l2vpn bridge group Missing Data'. That way the user can see s/he needs to do some investigating & follow-up. I don't want it to skip those rows as it will be hard to find out what is missing. I'm all ears if my logic doesn't make sense and you have a better way? I'm relatively new to this. Any input or suggestions wld be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: That's great :) Glad its working out. I think that logic is fine. You could potentially also log warnings out when a user were to run the script to highlight the issues verbosely as well to indicate that it was not executed flawlessly as a user may not check the output before trying to use it else where.

Comment: I like that idea of log warnings? How do suggest I incorporate that into the script? Wld it best to build that in the else statement of the convert function? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Yep exactly. Just before you return the default value add a print or better make a call to a logger and log it out as a warning.